# Why is `Mustache` undefined? (Using RequireJS)

Tags: javascript, requirejs, mustache, amd

I can see that the `mustache.js` file has been loaded, (code 200 in Firebug Net tab) so why do I get an error saying *"ReferenceError: Mustache is not defined"*?

I've looked at several related SO posts on this subject, but none seem to shed light on the issue. Any help is appreciated.

**Relevant HTML**

```
<div class="contact"></div>

<script data-main="js/modules/app.js" src="js/lib/require.min.js"></script>
```

**app.js**

```
var KBCOM = KBCOM || {};
(function (kbcom) {
  kbcom.app = {
    data: {
      kboucher: "{ \"firstName\": \"Kevin\", \"lastName\": \"Boucher\", \"dob\": \"1970-05-01T05:00:00.000Z\", \"emailAddress\": \"example@mail.com\", \"telephone\": \"512-555-1212\" }"
    },
    init: function () {
      kbcom.templates.loadTemplate(
        kbcom.templates.vcard,
        JSON.parse(this.data.kboucher),
        document.querySelector('.contact'));
    }
  };
}(KBCOM));
require.config({
  baseUrl: '/js/modules',
  paths: {
    Mustache: '/js/lib/mustache',
    domReady: '/js/lib/domReady'
  }
});
require(['domReady', 'templates', 'Mustache'], function (domReady) {
  domReady(function () {
    KBCOM.app.init();
  });
});
```

**templates.js**

```
var KBCOM = KBCOM || {};
(function (kbcom) {
  kbcom.templates = {
    vcard: '<ul>\
              <li class="fn">{{fisrtName}} {{lastName}}</li>\
              <li class="email">{{emailAddress}}</li>\
              <li class="tel">{{telephone}}</li>\
              <li class="bday">{{dob}}</li>\
            </ul>',
    loadTemplate: function (template, data, element) {
      element.innerHTML = Mustache.render(template, data);
    }
  };
}(KBCOM));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`templates.js` "requires" `Mustache`, therefore you need to define that dependency in `templates.js`. It also needs to be defined as a module, so you need to use `define` to properly create a module.

**app.js**

```
require(['domReady', 'templates'], function (domReady, templates) {

  //append templates to namespace
  KBCOM.templates = templates;

  domReady(function () {
    KBCOM.app.init();
  });
});
```

**templates.js**

```
define([    
  //dependencies
  'Mustache'
], function( Mustache ){ 

  //module code
  return {
    vcard: '...',
    loadTemplate: function ( template, data, element ) {
      element.innerHTML = Mustache.render( template, data );
    }
  };

});
```

Comment: _It may be that your templates loaded before Mustache_ But nothing is called until `domReady` when I call `KBCOM.app.init();` Shouldn't everything be loaded by that point? (I'm digging into your 2nd comment regarding structure now ...)

Comment: OK. I tweaked your suggestion a little to pass in my 'namespace' and it worked. (Going to update your answer with it.) Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @KevinBoucher You could have just returned the `template` object to `app.js` and attached it there. It would be cleaner and would adhere more to the AMD module definition. Updated my answer.

Comment: Interesting. _... and would adhere more to the AMD module definition_ Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

Require will bind the variables of the libraries to the parameters of the function given in the second parameter, so to use templates and Mustache in your code you should do the following:

```
require( [ 'domReady', 'templates', 'Mustache' ],
    function( domReady, templates, Mustache ) {
        domReady( function () {
            KBCOM.app.init();
        } );
    }
);
```

Comment: This suggestion produced the same result.